# Conditionally update/upsert embedded array with findOneAndUpdate in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in the following format:

```
[
  {
    "postId": ObjectId("62dffd0acb17483cf015375f"),
    "userId": ObjectId("62dff9584f5b702d61c81c3c"),
    "state": [
      {
        "id": ObjectId("62dffc49cb17483cf0153220"),
        "notes": "these are my custom notes!",
        "lvl": 3,
        
      },
      {
        "id": ObjectId("62dffc49cb17483cf0153221"),
        "notes": "hello again",
        "lvl": 0,
      },
    ]
  },
]
```

My goal is to be able to update and add an element in this array in the following situation:

1. If the ID of the new element is not in the `state` array, push the new element in the array
2. If the ID of the new element is in the `state` array and its `lvl` field is 0, update that element with the new information
3. If the ID of the new element exists in the array, and its `lvl` field is not 0, then nothing should happen. I will throw an error by seeing that no documents were matched.

Basically, to accomplish this I was thinking about using `findOneAndUpdate` with upsert, but  I am not sure how to tell the query to update the state if `lvl` is 0 or don't do anything if it is bigger than 0 when the match is found.

For solving (1) this is what I was able to come up with:

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
    {
        "postId": ObjectId("62dffd0acb17483cf015375f"),
        "userId": ObjectId("62dff9584f5b702d61c81c3c"),
        "state.id": {
            "$ne": ObjectId("62dffc49cb17483cf0153222"),
        },
    },
    {
        "$push": {"state": {"id": ObjectId("62dffc49cb17483cf0153222"), "lvl": 1}}
    },
    {
        "new": true,
        "upsert": true,
    }
)
```

What is the correct way to approach this issue? Should I just split the query into multiple ones?

**Edit**: as of now I have done this in more than one query (one to fetch the document, then I iterate over its state array to check if the ID exists in it, and then I perform (1), (2) and (3) in a normal if-else clause)

Comment: Where you are executing this query in mongo shell? or in nodejs with mongoose npm or mongodb npm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *If the ID of the new element exists in the array, and its lvl field is not 0, then nothing should happen. I will throw an error by seeing that no documents where matched.*

**First thing** FYI,

- upsert is not possible in the nested array
- upsert will not add new elements to the array
- upsert can add a new document with the new element
- if you want to throw an error if the record does not present then you don't need upsert

**Second thing**, you can achieve this in one query by using an [update with aggregation pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) in MongoDB 4.2,

> Note: Here i must inform you, this query will respond updated document but there will be no flag or any clue if this query fulfilled your first situation or second situation, or the third situation out of 3, you have to check in your client-side code through query response.

- check conditions for `postId` and `userId` fields only
- we are going to update `state` field under `$set` stage
- check the condition if the provided id is present in `state`'s `id`?

  - true, `$map` to iterate loop of `state` array

    - check conditions for `id` and `lvl: 0`?

      - true, `$mergeObjects` to merge current object with the new information
      - false, it will not do anything
  - false, then add that new element in `state` array, by `$concatArrays` operator

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    postId: ObjectId("62dffd0acb17483cf015375f"),
    userId: ObjectId("62dff9584f5b702d61c81c3c")
  },
  [{
    $set: {
      state: {
        $cond: [
          { $in: [ObjectId("62dffc49cb17483cf0153221"), "$state.id"] },
          {
            $map: {
              input: "$state",
              in: {
                $cond: [
                  {
                    $and: [
                      { $eq: ["$$this.id", ObjectId("62dffc49cb17483cf0153221")] },
                      { $eq: ["$$this.lvl", 0] }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $mergeObjects: [
                      "$$this",
                      { 
                        // update your new fields here
                        "notes": "new note" 
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  "$$this"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$state",
              [
                // add new element
                {
                  "id": ObjectId("62dffc49cb17483cf0153221"),
                  "lvl": 1
                }
              ]
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }],
  { returnNewDocument: true }
)
```

[Playrgound](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yQ062Ursjfa)

**Third thing**, you can execute 2 update queries,

- The first query, for the case: element does not present and it will push a new element in `state`

```
let response = db.collection.findOneAndUpdate({
  postId: ObjectId("62dffd0acb17483cf015375f"),
  userId: ObjectId("62dff9584f5b702d61c81c3c"),
  "state.id": { $ne: ObjectId("62dffc49cb17483cf0153221") }
},
{
  $push: {
    state: {
      id: ObjectId("62dffc49cb17483cf0153221"),
      lvl: 1
    }
  }
},
{
  returnNewDocument: true
})
```

The second query on the base of if the response of the above query is `null` then this query will execute,

- This will check state `id` and `lvl: 0` conditions if conditions are fulfilled then execute the update fields operation, it will return null if the document is not found
- You can throw if this will return null otherwise do stuff with response data and response success

```
if (response == null) {
  response = db.collection.findOneAndUpdate({
    postId: ObjectId("62dffd0acb17483cf015375f"),
    userId: ObjectId("62dff9584f5b702d61c81c3c"),
    state: { 
      $elemMatch: {
        id: ObjectId("62dffc49cb17483cf0153221"),
        lvl: 0
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      // add your update fields
      "state.$.notes": "new note"
    }
  },
  {
    returnNewDocument: true
  });
  
  // not found and throw an error
  if (response == null) {
    return {
      // throw error;
    };
  }
}

// do stuff with "response" data and return result

return {
  // success;
};
```

> Note: As per the above options, I would recommend you that I explained in the **Third thing** that you can execute 2 update queries.

Comment: I like the last approach. Just a quick question, is there any way to throw if the document wasn't updated? For example, as you can see in this mongoplayground https://mongoplayground.net/p/rpvOx3PPirF I am checking for object with ID `62dffc49cb17483cf0153220` which does not update anything since `lvl > 0`. Could I check this somehow?

Comment: as I explained in the last approach, it will return null when you use `findOneAndUpdate` method.

Comment: Thanks! Just to be clear, the mongoplayground does not return null because I am executing an `update`, correct?

Comment: right, mongoplayground is different, it is just only for debugged purposes, we can just estimate request, query, and response.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying became possible with the introduction [pipelined updates](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/), here is how I would do it by using [$concatArrays](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) to concat the exists `state` array with the new input and [$ifNull](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) in case of an upsert to init the empty value, like so:

```
const inputObj = {
                  "id": ObjectId("62dffc49cb17483cf0153222"),
                  "lvl": 1
                };

db.collection.findOneAndUpdate({
  "postId": ObjectId("62dffd0acb17483cf015375f"),
  "userId": ObjectId("62dff9584f5b702d61c81c3c")
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      state: {
        $ifNull: [
          "$state",
          []
        ]
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      state: {
        $concatArrays: [
          {
            $map: {
              input: "$state",
              in: {
                $mergeObjects: [
                  {
                    $cond: [
                      {
                        $and: [
                          {
                            $in: [
                              inputObj.id,
                              "$state.id"
                            ]
                          },
                          {
                            $eq: [
                              inputObj.lvl,
                              0
                            ]
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      inputObj,
                      {},
                      
                    ]
                  },
                  "$$this"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            $cond: [
              {
                $not: {
                  $in: [
                    inputObj.id,
                    "$state.id"
                  ]
                }
              },
              [
                
              ],
              []
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  "new": true,
  "upsert": true
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/c77lcxOma6Q)

Prior to version 4.2 and the introduction of this feature what you're trying to do was not possible using the naive update syntax, If you are using an older version then you'd have to split this into 2 separate calls, first a `findOne` to see if the document exists, and only then an update based on that. obviously this can cause stability issue's if you have high update volume.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This is not exactly what I am looking for (and probably I confused you with my approach of the question). When you look for a state that already exists in the array with lvl 0, the update is not matched and an upsert is triggered. You can see what I mean in here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/PlNEinHf0Xe where two documents are returned instead of one. Same for when you look for a state that exists with `level > 0`. So requirement (2) and (3) are not working properly.

Comment: I completely skipped these requirements, I have edited my answer to adjust. the approach is still the same - just more conditions within the update body.

Comment: Thanks again! Could you explain what the `[]` in the line 72 in mongoplayground is for?

Comment: Also, note that when I run this mongoplayground the output array does not contain the `lvl` field updated for the card `62dffc49cb17483cf0153222`